# Confusing (*this) cast of a pointer

Tags: c++, casting, ros

This is code from Transform.h in ROS ([link](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transform.html)) in the Transform class.

```
/**@brief Return the transform of the vector */
TFSIMD_FORCE_INLINE Vector3 operator*(const Vector3& x) const
{
    return (*this)(x);
}
```

Can someone explain what this piece of code is doing? Here is what I think (for context, I have a few years experience as a C programmer, first time developing in C++.)

The function is called when the following is invoked

```
object_of_type_Transform * object_of_type_Vector3
```

It then casts the Vector3 object into a Transform object and returns that as a result (I am quite unclear about how this can be possible as the two types do not seem compatible).

But the result being returned is a Vector3... and this is where my mental model breaks down.

Additionally, the function is supposed to be transforming a Vector3 point based on the Transform class... so my understanding is definitely flawed somewhere.

I would appreciate any insights.

Thanks

EDIT

Thanks for the reply! The function right above is:

```
/**@brief Return the transform of the vector */
TFSIMD_FORCE_INLINE Vector3 operator()(const Vector3& x) const
{
    return Vector3(m_basis[0].dot(x) + m_origin.x(), 
    m_basis[1].dot(x) + m_origin.y(), 
    m_basis[2].dot(x) + m_origin.z());
}

/**@brief Return the transform of the vector */
TFSIMD_FORCE_INLINE Vector3 operator*(const Vector3& x) const
{
    return (*this)(x);
}
```

I understand, now, whats going on. Thanks again.

Comment: There's no cast. 0/10 bad troll.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It then casts the Vector3 object into a Transform object and returns that as a result

No. No cast is taking place; this:

```
return (*this)(x);
```

is equivalent to:

```
return this->operator()(x);
```

In both cases the code is invoking `Transform::operator()` and passing `x` to it. The parentheses in the first code are necessary because `()` binds stronger than `*` so without the parentheses around `*this` the code would be equivalent to `return *(this(x));` – a compilation error.

Incidentally, this is quite idiomatic C++ code but I can see how the syntax can be confusing for C programmers (where, after all, you cannot overload operators, let alone `operator()`).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Universe makes order again!